# Error while compiling a project which includes CPLEX tool

Tags: c++

I am working on the project which has to include the CPLEX tool at some point. 
More in detail, I have the following classes implemented 
(i.e. the corresponding files): Random.cpp, Instance.cpp, Timer.cpp. Solution.cpp which are included into Hybrid_ea.cpp which also have to include cplex library.
Finally, the project has been executed by running Algorithm.cpp (the main() function defined here).

I want to run the project on Linux platform, creating Makefile which looks like:

```
TARGET = Algorithm 

CXXFLAGS = -ansi -O3
GENOBJS = Random.o
#CPLOBJS = Timer.o Random.o Instance.o Hybrid_ea.o
GREOBJS = Timer.o Random.o Instance.o Solution.o Hybrid_ea.o

SYSTEM     = x86-64_linux
LIBFORMAT  = static_pic
CPLEXDIR      =  /home/root/Desktop/projects/software/cplex-12.5/cplex
CONCERTDIR    =  /home/root/Desktop/projects/software/cplex-12.5/concert
CCC = g++
CCOPT = -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -std=c++11 -fpermissive -w
CPLEXBINDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/bin/$(BINDIST)
CPLEXLIBDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)
CONCERTLIBDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)
CCLNFLAGS = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -lilocplex -lcplex -L$(CONCERTLIBDIR) -lconcert -lm -pthread
CLNFLAGS  = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -lcplex -lm -pthread
CONCERTINCDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/include
CPLEXINCDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/include
CCFLAGS = $(CCOPT) -I$(CPLEXINCDIR) -I$(CONCERTINCDIR)


all: ${TARGET}

Algorithm: Algorithm.o $(GREOBJS)
   $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS)  Algorithm.o $(GREOBJS) -o Algorithm $(CCLNFLAGS)

Algorithm.o: Algorithm.cpp
   $(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) Algorithm.cpp -o Algorithm.o 

clean:
   @rm -f *~ *.o ${TARGET} core
```

The linking process is somehow wrong. I checked, my CPLEX version is the right one since the others, simpler projects can be executed;

The full output given when trying to compile the project:

```
g++ -c -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -std=c++11 -fpermissive -w -I/home/root/Desktop/projects/LCAPS_software/cplex-12.5/cplex/include -I/home/root/Desktop/projects/LCAPS_software/cplex-12.5/concert/include Algorithm.cpp -o Algorithm.o 
g++ -ansi -O3   -c -o Timer.o Timer.cc
g++ -ansi -O3   -c -o Random.o Random.cc
g++ -ansi -O3   -c -o Instance.o Instance.cpp
g++ -ansi -O3   -c -o Solution.o Solution.cpp
g++ -ansi -O3   -c -o hybrid_ea.o hybrid_ea.cpp
In file included from hybrid_ea.cpp:22:0:
hybrid_ea.h:39:10: fatal error: ilcplex/ilocplex.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hybrid_ea.o' failed
make: *** [hybrid_ea.o] Error 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will probably be more helpful to show the full command-line that asks for the compilation of `hybrid_ea.o` rather than your makefile.  With the actual command line, we can see what's going on...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.         

//other include classes
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>


  ILOSTLBEGIN

//class definition
class hybrid_ea
{

//here some Cplex stuff are called in some of calss methods
}

Comment: Seems the error occurred at the line #include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>

Comment: Rather than posting only the error, please include all the preceding output from trying to compile your project.

Comment: Now, I added the output (by updating my post).

Comment: And that allowed me propose a much better (hopefully!) answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the file `Algorithm.cpp` is compiled with appropriate options for finding the CPLEX include files:

```
-I/home/root/Desktop/projects/LCAPS_software/cplex-12.5/cplex/include
-I/home/root/Desktop/projects/LCAPS_software/cplex-12.5/concert/include
```

As `hybrid_ea.h` also tries to include some CPLEX header files, the compilation of `hybrid_ea.cpp` should also have the options above.

If the makefile that you posted in your question is complete, then I suspect that the issue is the following: you didn't define a specific command to compile any `.cc`  or `.cpp`  file, except for `Algorithm.cpp`.  Therefore, all other files are compiled using a default command `g++ -ansi -O3 -c -o [file].o [file].cpp`.  And this default command doesn't have the include directives for the location of the CPLEX libraries.

As explained in ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html, these files are compiled using make's implicit rules.  The implicit rule for C++ files is to use `$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)`.  Notice how this rule uses `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` rather than the variable `CCFLAGS`  that you defined at the end of your makefile to include the proper include directives.

So changing the end of your makefile to the following should work:

```
CPPFLAGS = $(CCOPT) -I$(CPLEXINCDIR) -I$(CONCERTINCDIR)

all: ${TARGET}

Algorithm: Algorithm.o $(GREOBJS)
   $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS)  Algorithm.o $(GREOBJS) -o Algorithm $(CCLNFLAGS)

clean:
   @rm -f *~ *.o ${TARGET} core
```

Once you define the variable `CPPFLAGS`, it will be used automatically to compile any `.cpp` file that you have in your project.